# Is DLV on dnssec deprecated?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dnssec

I'm trying to set up a recursive DNS that also have its own zone using bind.

Now I want to upgrade it to use dnssec but as far as I understood I have to use DLV if I don't own a domain name.

However the few guides that I could find say that you need to sign up in `dlv.isc.org` which doesn't exist. And a book I was reading about DNSSEC tells that DLV was going to get deprecated so that's why i'm wondering.
(If you know any step by step guide to set it up would be appreciated too)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You want the server to act as a _validating recursive resolver_ or do you want other resolvers to be able to validate your private domain?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I want it to be a validating recursive resolver but also have my own LAN zone like myzone.local that also uses dnssec

Comment: Your private zone does not need validating, unless every computer is using a validating resolver instead of a stub resolver. In that case you can set up a DLV on each of them, pointing to your server.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I think I do need to validate it, the aim of the laboratory is to do a dns spoof attack before and after using dnssec, so if I don't validate the local zone I would be able to commit a dns spoof attack as far as I know

Comment: "if i dont own a domain name. " If you want to configure an authoritative nameserver AND make sure it gets queries, it needs to be properly delegated from some registry/TLD nameservers which means in turn either you own this domain name or you have full control over its DNS delegation... As you seem to be a beginner in the DNS world I STRONGLY suggest you stay away from DNSSEC (and hence from DLV) for now, and wait for some time to completely understand how the DNS works and then maybe think about adding DNSSEC feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the `dlv.isc.org` server is not running any more, you can still set another DNSSEC Lookaside server in your Bind 9 config through the [dnssec-lookaside](https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#options-statement-definition-and-usage) option. If the key for `example.com` can not be validated, the lookaside server's name will be appended to it and the validation will start over against the lookaside server's trusted key. I didn't test, but I believe that will not solve your problem: a private domain as `lan.` can these days be positively validated as non existent, so the lookaside query will not be performed.

So what can be done to secure a `lan.` zone? It depends on the usage:

1. The DNS server, which you want to use as both *validating recursive resolver* and authoritative server for the `lan.` zone does not require any additional configuration (I assume the `dnssec-validation` is already on):

   - it will serve the `lan.` zone from the zone file and return an answer **without** the `AD` flag,
   - when a query for other domains comes in, it will perform a recursive query, validate the results and only if they are valid return an answer **with** the `AD` flag. If the domain does not validate a `SERVFAIL` will be issued.
2. The *stub resolvers*, which use your DNS server, rely on the validating behaviour of your DNS server, so they will resolve `lan.` without issues. However, since the communication between *stub resolver* and server is unencrypted, the results can be modified in transit. You might use TSIG signatures or TLS to protect it.
3. The *validating stub resolvers* require you to add **trusted anchors** to their configuration.

I doubt you want to set up a Bind9 server on every **client** machine to act as a *validating stub resolver* (there are better alternatives like **systemd-resolved**, **dnsmasq** or **unbound**), but if that is the case, you need to retrieve first the key for your `lan.` zone:

```
piotr@akela:~$ dig lan. DNSKEY +short
257 3 13 nnbo5DS5vyxB0OjUd7GbcrmXY7TgdGstk4xqXpu2wvXyoFa0YRqjLcHM QJGMguTrKJVYklMNRQXrStvawSF5eg==
```

Then you will need to add the key as trusted, allow recursive queries just from `localhost` and forward the requests to the "real" DNS server (let's say its on `192.168.0.1`):

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    listen-on { localhost; };
    listen-on-v6 { localhost; };
    recursion yes;
    allow-query { localhost; };
    forwarders { 192.168.0.1; };
};
trusted-keys {
    lan. 257 3 13 "nnbo5DS5vyxB0OjUd7GbcrmXY7TgdGstk4xqXpu2wvXyoFa0YRqjLcHM QJGMguTrKJVYklMNRQXrStvawSF5eg==";
};
```

At the end you just need to add `localhost` as the only DNS server in `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver ::1;
```

**Edit**: **systemd-resolved** configuration is even simpler: just add your DNSKEY to a file named `/etc/dnssec-trust-anchors.d/<your_name>.positive`:

```
lan. IN DNSKEY 257 3 13 nnbo5DS5vyxB0OjUd7GbcrmXY7TgdGstk4xqXpu2wvXyoFa0YRqjLcHM QJGMguTrKJVYklMNRQXrStvawSF5eg==
```

and force DNSSEC in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`:

```
DNSSEC=yes
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time and such a detailed answer :D